# C# Error In Loop Syntax

Tags: c#

Here is what I want to do:

1. The user enters a beginning value
2. Enter the last value
3. The program asks if the user wants to count upwards to the last value or downwards
4. The user responds and the program (to increase the value type (I), to increase the value type (I) )

Example: countdown from (Num1=10) to (Num2=1) by (fac=-1)

Expected Result:

```
Welcome To The Counter System
==============================
Enter the first number: 10
==============================
Enter the last number: 1
==============================
**To Increase The Value Type (I)**
**To Decrease The Value Type (D)**
D
==============================
Enter The Factor: 1
==============================
RESULT
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

My code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome To The Counter System");
            Console.WriteLine("==============================");

            Console.Write("Enter the first number: ");
            decimal Num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("==============================");

            Console.Write("Enter the last number: ");
            decimal Num2 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("==============================");

            Console.WriteLine("**To Increase The Value Type (I)**");
            Console.WriteLine("**To Decrease The Value Type (D)**");

            char Op = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

            if (Op == 'I' || Op == 'i')
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Increment Factor : ");
                decimal fac = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

                for (decimal beg = Num1; Num2 >= Num1; beg = Num1 + fac)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(beg);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (Op == 'D' || Op == 'd')
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Ddecrement Factor : ");
                decimal fac = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("==============================");
                Console.WriteLine("RESULT");

                for (decimal beg = Num1; Num2 <= Num1; beg = (Num1 - fac))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(beg);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are initializing "beg" as the running variable. But then you do not actually use it in the check part of the for loop. Also this does not appear to be in any way a proper Increment. Your intention is less then clear and does not remotely allign with how you use a for loop.

Comment: So... what happens? What do you expect to happen? Also, You Don't Have To Write Like This....

Comment: 1) don't make your question unnecessarily ugly 2) format your code as it makes it easier for the people trying to help you, 3) `Doesn't Work As Expected` is not a description of a problem

Comment: When is Num2 >= Num1 in your loop?  Your `break;` takes you out of the loop, by the way.

Comment: The more I look at it, the less it appears that you even understand the most basic part of a for loop. It is not really possible to help you if you are so far off the mark that we can not even guess what your intention was.

Comment: You need to learn [how to debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @AbdulhamidYusuf it would be better if you edited your question with what you want, rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is quite vague, because you're not explaining what you're expecting in the first place. However, I do see there is something wrong with the for loop if you're expecting to increment the value of Num1 with the fac variable as a result of the for loop:

1. You won't be incrementing Num1 with the fac variable. You'll need a statement within 
   the for loop to increase the value of Num1.
2. The part with **"beg = Num1 + fac"** prevents the beg variable from incrementing. For instance, if Num1 has the value of 0.0m (a decimal value) and fac has the value of 1.1m, then beg's value will always remain 1.1m. This defeats the purpose of the incrementer that the for loop relies on to prevent an infinite loop.

Here's the updated piece of code. I did remove the input functionality for simplicity's sake:

```
decimal Num1 = 0.0m;
decimal Num2 = 2.2m;

char Op = 'I';

if (Op == 'I' || Op == 'i')
{
    decimal fac = 1.1m;

    for (decimal beg = Num1; beg <= Num2; beg += fac)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value of beg is: " + beg);

        Num1 = beg;

        Console.WriteLine("Value of Num1 has been updated to: " + Num1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow ! It Worked, I felt Disappointed For A Moment When Reading The Comments, But Now Everything is Okay ty..